# Is it possible to make any abelian group homomorphism into a linear map?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, modules

Let $G$
  and $H$
  be abelian groups and let $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$
  be a group homomorphism. Can we define a nontrivial scalar multiplication on $G$
  (from some field $F$
 ) and another nontrivial scalar multiplication on $H$
  (from $F$
 ), thereby making them vector spaces, such that $\varphi$
  becomes a linear map? If the answer is yes, then would this also work if we made $G$ and $H$ into modules over some ring $R$?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so we can always treat $\varphi$ as a linear map of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

However, it is not always possible to view an abelian group as a vector space over a field. For example, the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ (with addition) is not a vector space over any field.

Why not? Well, suppose $\mathbb{Z}$ was (the underlying group of) a vector space over a field $k$. First, note that $k$ must have characteristic $0$ - if $k$ had characteristic $p\not=0$ then we'd have $1+1+...+1$ ($p$ times) equals $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

So $k$ has characteristic $0$, which means $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $k$. (In fact, we may assume without loss of generality that $k=\mathbb{Q}$, but we don't need to.) What can ${1\over 2}\cdot 1$ be (where the ${1\over 2}$ is in $k$ and the $1$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$)? Whatever integer this is, it must satisfy ${1\over 2}\cdot 1+{1\over 2}\cdot 1=1$. But there is no integer with this property.

Answer (score 8):

Notice that any commutative $G$ is a $\Bbb Z$-module in a natural way: just define $n \cdot g$ to be $g^n$. Check that the usual properties for modules are satisfied.

Now, if $\varphi$ is a group morphism, then $\varphi (g^n) = \varphi (g) ^n$, or in our $\Bbb Z$-module notation: $\varphi (n \cdot g) = n \cdot \varphi (g)$, i.e. $\varphi$ is $\Bbb Z$-linear.

On the other hand, not all groups can be given a vector space stucture. For instance, if $G$ is a finite group (write it in additive notation) and $d = |G|$, and if $K \supseteq \Bbb Q$, then $d \cdot g = 0$ for all $g \in G$. Multiplying by the scalar $\frac 1 d \in \Bbb Q$ would give $g=0$.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incomplete - all you've shown is that no finite group can be the underlying group of a vector space *over a field of characteristic $0$.* But there are fields of [nonzero characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)#Case_of_fields)! Andreas' answer below gives the right approach to building a finite group which cannot be a vector space.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I agree with you: my last paragraph was meant only to show that in general the problem has a negative answer. Your argument is much better, since it shows that if the characteristic of the field is $\ne 2$, the only possible multiplication by scalars is the trivial one: $q \cdot g = 0$.

Comment: @AlexM. The "trivial multiplication" isn't a valid one - vector spaces satisfy $1_k\cdot v=v$. And my argument does *not* only apply to characteristic $\not=2$ - note that I first show the characteristic must be $0$, so $\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be the underlying group of a vector space over *any* field.

Answer (score 7):

To record another example, a finite vector space has order a power of a prime. So if the order of the abelian group $G$ is not a power of a prime, it cannot be turned into a vector space.

Actually, even if the abelian group $G$ is of order $p^{n}$, for some prime $p$, then if it can be turned into a vector space over a field $F$, then it will also be a vector space over the field with $p$ elements. And then  $p x = 0$ has to hold for all $x \in G$. Conversely, if this conditions holds, then even if $G$ is not finite, it can be turned into a vector space over the field with $p$ elements.

---

**Addendum.** Even if $G$ and $H$ can be turned into vector spaces, it is not always the case that $\phi$ can be made linear. In fact, if $G$ and $H$ can be made into vector spaces over a field $F$, then they can be made into vector spaces over the prime field $P$ contained in $F$, thus over the rationals if $F$ has characteristic zero, over the field with $p$ elements if $F$ has prime characteristic $p$. And any group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ will be a $P$-linear map.

But take for instance $G = H = \mathbb{R}$. Then the only $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps from $G$ to $H$ are the multiplications by a fixed real number. Whereas there are many more group homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$, see [Hamel bases](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html). So if you make $G$ and $H$ into rational vector spaces, all group homomorphisms will be linear. If you attempt to make them into real vector space, this is not the case anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Not ANY morphism pf groups allows this, however I will show a sufficient condition for this to be true.

In the following question

[Prove this homomorphism gives an equivalent definition of Linear Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802447/prove-this-homomorphism-gives-an-equivalent-definition-of-linear-space)

we provide an equivalent definition to linear space, in terms of a homomorphism from the product group of a field, and the group of automorphisms of an abelian group. There we prove how this homomorphism provides us with a definition of scalar prodcut, and the elements of the vector space are obviously the elements of the abelian group.

Let $G$ and $H$ be turned into vector spaces by this manner, and using the same field. This means we have two homomorphisms $*_1:\mathbb K(\cdot)\rightarrow\{GfG\}$ and $*_2:\mathbb K(\cdot)\rightarrow\{HfH\}$, here we use $\{GfG\}$ to represent the group of automorphisms of $G$. We know $*_1(a)$, for any $a\in\mathbb K$, is an automorphism of $G$, and this defines our scalar product, the same is true for $*_2(a)$.

We know $\phi(u+v)=\phi u+\phi v$. Then, we can say that a functor (homomorphism) $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a linear map if the following condition holds:

$$\phi\circ*_1(a)=*_2(a)\circ\phi$$ for every $a$ in the field. This condition simply means $\phi(au)=a(\phi u)$, for every element in th field.

In conclusion, if $G$ and $H$ can be made into linear spaces by means of the homomorphisms $*_1:G\rightarrow\{GfG\}$ and $*_2:H\rightarrow\{HfH\}$, and if the morphism $\phi$ commutes with the morhpsims in $Im(*_1)$, $Im(*_2)$, in the sense we just made clear, then we can say $\phi$ is a linear transformation from the linear space $G$ into the linear space $H$.