# Prove this homomorphism gives an equivalent definition of Linear Space

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb V(\oplus)$ be an abelian group and $\mathbb K(+,\cdot)$ a field; of course $\mathbb K(\cdot)$ is the group under product. We represent the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb V(\oplus)$ with the notation $\{\mathbb Vf\mathbb V\}$, and let $*:\mathbb K(\cdot)\rightarrow\{\mathbb Vf\mathbb V\}$ be a homomorphism such that $*(a+b)(u)=*(a)(u)\oplus*(b)(u)$. Prove we have defined a linear space.

The elements of the abelian group are the vectors, while scalar multiplication is defined by the homomorphism. We need to prove the relations that hold for scalar product. Basically we are saying that a linear space exists when we have a homomorphism between a field and a group of automorphisms of an abelian group that satisfies one condition.

Comment: What have you tried?  What needs to be checked to confirm this is a linear space?

Comment: Ill post the solution in the following days. Its a problem I came up with and Im posting to see if anyone finds it interesting.

Comment: [Uncurrying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) your $*$ operator into $*:\Bbb K(\cdot) \times \Bbb V \to \Bbb V$ turns this into the standard definition, but you've found a neat way to encode the associativity (and invertibility) of the product $a(bu)$

Comment: If you're looking for abstract characterizations of a vector space, the following [wikipedia excerpt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Generalizations) might be interesting to you: *any ring R can be viewed as a preadditive category with a single object. With this understanding, a left R-module is nothing but a (covariant) additive functor from R to the category Ab of abelian groups.* A vector space is then just a module where the ring $R$ is a field.

Comment: In the future: if you're going to give a problem where you know the solution as a "challenge" to other users, then please make it clear that this is what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The homomorphism $*$ maps elements of the fiels into automorphisms for the abelian group. The condition given on $*$ makes it so that $*(a+b)$ applied to $u$, gives the same result if we operate $*a(u)$ and $*b(u)$ in the group. Equivalently, $(a+b)*u=(a*u)\oplus(b*u)$.

Obviously, the scalar product is defined in terms of the homomorphism $*$ in such a way that $*(a)$ is the automorpphism that maps $u\mapsto a*u$. Since the objects in the image of $*$ are automorphisms, we have $*a(u\oplus v)=*a(u)\oplus*a(v)$, which is another way of saying $a*(u\oplus v)=(a*u)\oplus (a*v)$.

Secondly, the fact that $*$ is a homomorphism means that $1\in\mathbb K(\cdot)$ is the identity morphism for our abelian group. Also, $*(a\cdot b)=*(a)\circ*(b)$ because $*$ is an homomorphism with composition as operation in the image. Another way of expressing this is by $(a\cdot b)*u=a*(b*u)$. This gives a scalar producto of the objects in the field and the abelian group, turning it into a linear space over $\mathbb K$.